# Props Passing 2 objects when only 1 is needed, React

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying only to pass one value, but it has currently two values here. It's passing the selected hive, and an additional array. I tried removing props but then it won't pass anything. I tried adding another hook for it but I may be doing it incorrectly. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

App.js

```
// General Imports
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";


// Pages Imports
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage/HomePage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "./pages/RegisterPage/RegisterPage";
import AddHivePage from "./pages/AddHive/AddHive";
import UpdateHivePage from "./pages/UpdateHivePage/UpdateHivePage";
import InspectionPage from "./pages/InspectionPage/InspectionPage";


// Component Imports
import Navbar from "./components/NavBar/NavBar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";

// Util Imports
import PrivateRoute from "./utils/PrivateRoute";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {

  const [selectedHive, setSelectedHive] = useState('')


  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <PrivateRoute>
              <HomePage setSelectedHive={setSelectedHive} />
            </PrivateRoute>
          }
        />
        <Route path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/addhive" element={<PrivateRoute><AddHivePage /></PrivateRoute>}/>
        <Route path="/hives/update/:id"  element={<PrivateRoute><UpdateHivePage selectedHive={selectedHive} /></PrivateRoute>}/>
        <Route path="/inspections/all/:id"  element={<PrivateRoute><InspectionPage selectedHive={selectedHive}  /></PrivateRoute>}/>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Homepage

```
import React from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Hive from "../../components/Hive/Hive";

const HomePage = (props) => {


  return (
    <div className="container">
      
      <Hive setSelectedHive={props.setSelectedHive} />
      <Link to="/addhive">Add Hive!</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Inspection component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DisplayInspections from '../DisplayInspections/DisplayInspections';

import useAuth from '../../hooks/useAuth';
import axios from 'axios';


const Inspections= (selectedHive, props) => {
    const [user, token] = useAuth();
    const [inspections, setInspections] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchInspections(props.setSelectedValue);
    }, [])
    const fetchInspections = async () => {
        try {console.log(selectedHive)
            let response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/inspections/all/${selectedHive}`,  {
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
            },
            });
            setInspections(response.data);
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.data);
        }
    };


    
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>List of Inspections</h1>
            <DisplayInspections inspections={inspections} setSelectedHive={props.setSelectedHive} />
            
        </div>
      );

}
export default Inspections;
```

This is where I am trying to send the data from for my axios call.
Display.jsx

```
import React from "react";

import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const DisplayHives = ({hives, setSelectedHive}) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    function handleClick(id){
        setSelectedHive(id);
        navigate(`/hives/update/${id}`)
    }
    function handleClickInspection(id){
        setSelectedHive(id);
        navigate(`/inspections/all/${id}`)
    }
    
    return ( 
        <>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {hives.map((hive)=> {
                        return(
                            <tr key={hive.id} >
                            <td>{hive.hive_number}</td>
                            <td>{hive.inspection_date} </td> 
                            <td> <button onClick={() => handleClickInspection(hive.id)}>Inspections</button></td>
                            <td>

                                <button onClick={() => handleClick(hive.id)}>Update</button>
                                </td>
                           
                            
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </>
     );
}
 
export default DisplayHives;
```

Comment: I don't understand well what your trouble is correctly.
So are you going to remove props in inspection component?
But you have been using props.setSelectedValue in that component.

Comment: I provided an answer on your [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72348762/17562044) question and you haven't replied even.

Comment: My apologies, that issue has been fixed. I have fixed that :)